# Next ReferenceError: location is not defined

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

Getting the `location is not defined` error at my next.js project

```
⨯ node_modules/next/dist/client/performance-relayer.js (20:20) @ location
 ⨯ ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/<PATH>/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/<PATH>/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/<PATH>/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (dashboard/layout.tsx:14:69)
    at (ssr)/./app/(withlayout)/dashboard/layout.tsx (/media/<PATH>/.next/server/app/(withlayout)/dashboard/page.js:226:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/<PATH>/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
null
```

The component is

```
"use client";
import { FaHome } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { BsFolder, BsGrid1X2 } from 'react-icons/bs'
import {cn} from "@/lib/cn";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import {router} from "next/client";


const layout = ({ children }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  }


  return (
    <div className='bg-[#18191b] min-h-screen w-full'>
      <div className='w-full flex mt-16'>
        <div className='sidebar w-[300px] p-5 h-[calc(100vh-70px)] fixed'>
          <div className='px-2 py-2 flex justify-start gap-5 items-center mb-3'>
            <img className='w-[40px] h-[40px] rounded-full' src="https://svgshare.com/i/7aS.svg" alt="image" />
            <div className='flex justify-center flex-col items-start'>
              <span className='text-[#e0dddd] font-bold text-md'>User's Name</span>
              <span className='text-[#c4c0c0] text-sm'>Free</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul className='px-4 flex flex-col gap-2'>
            <li>
              <Link
                href='/'
                className={`text-[#e0dddd] px-2 py-2 flex justify-start items-center gap-2 ${pathname === '/' ? 'bg-[#ffffff26]' : ''} rounded-[4px]`}
              >
                <span className='text-xl'><FaHome /></span>
                <span className='font-medium'>Home</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href='/projects'
                className={`text-[#e0dddd] px-2 py-2 flex justify-start items-center gap-2 ${pathname === '/projects' ? 'bg-[#ffffff26]' : ''} rounded-[4px]`}
              >
                <span className='text-xl'><BsFolder /></span>
                <span className='font-medium'>Projects</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href='/templates'
                className={`text-[#e0dddd] px-2 py-2 flex justify-start items-center gap-2 ${pathname === '/templates' ? 'bg-[#ffffff26]' : ''} rounded-[4px]`}
              >
                <span className='text-xl'><BsGrid1X2 /></span>
                <span className='font-medium'>Templates</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className='ml-[300px] w-[calc(100%-300px)]'>
          <div className='py-4 pr-4'>
            <main className={cn("grid place-items-center")}>{children}</main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default layout
```

I do not use location or window object anywhere in my project, despite of getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
instead of import {router} from "next/client";

then const router = useRouter() and use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).